# How to get a piece of data from the last line of a text file on another website

Tags: javascript, text, web, line

I'm really a newbie with javascript and I'm having trouble developing code that will allow my website to automatically update certain weather values that are provided by another website as a text file on a daily basis. I know that there are many ways to read a text file from another url, but I'm only interested in the values in the last line of the text file, particularly. (The text file gets longer by 1 line each day as a new set of data is added). Each line in the text file always contains 16 pieces of data separated by spaces as shown below.

2012 03 08  140     86     1330      0    -999   B6.5   6  0  0  4  0  0  0
2012 03 09  146     96     1240      1    -999   B8.8  10  1  0  1  0  0  0
2012 03 10  149     89     1120      0    -999   B7.0   9  1  0  4  0  0  0
2012 03 11  131    103     1260      2    -999   B5.6   4  0  0  1  0  0  0
2012 03 12  115     89      650      0    -999   B4.7   4  0  0  2  0  0  0

What I'm interested in ultimately doing is outputting the fourth data element (in this case, "89", on to my webpage.

As I see it, I have three problems to solve: 1) access the text file at the other webwsite, 2) Read the last line of the file into a string variable, 3) Place the fourth data element of the last line into a string variable and output it to the webpage.

Can someone show me a relatively quick way to do this?

Comment: HTTP does not provide "line" access to a file. At most you can request a specific range of bytes. If it's a small file to fetch, you'd better off fetching the entire thing and doing the line analysis on your own server.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with JavaScript because it cannot load pages from other web sites, due to the [Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript). To do what you propose, you need to do it on a server, not on a web page.